# Changing selection color and adding a marker image on shape select in MapWinGis

Tags: c#, gis, shapes, shapefile, mapwingis

I have a project in C# Windows Forms using MapWinGis.ocx.

I would like to **add a marker (pin.png)** and **change shape color**,
**when I select a shape** (using mouse select or programmatically).

How can I do it in MapWinGis 5.3.0.0?

What I tried for changing the shape highlight/selection color:

```
    MapLayersHandlerResult ml = new MapLayersHandlerResult();
    foreach (string fileName in fileNames) //for opening multiple files
    {
        ml = _mapLayersHandler.FileOpenHandler(fileName);

        Shapefile sf = ((Shapefile)_mapLayersHandler.CurrentMapLayer.LayerObject);
        sf.SelectionAppearance = tkSelectionAppearance.saSelectionColor;
        sf.SelectionColor = classes.Colors.ColorToUInteger(Color.Red); //tring to change selection color / shape
    }
    if (!ml.success)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ml.errMsg);
    }
```

but is not working...the selected shape color is still yellow.

thanks advanced.